# React.cloneElement / HOC / Transclusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transclusion

I'm putting together a table control with React which pretty much follows this pattern all the way down to the cells:

```
class Table extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        tableClass: PropTypes.string,
        columnDefinitions: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { tableClass, children } = this.props;
        const passthroughProps = except(this.props, ['id', 'key', 'children', 'form', 'tableClass']);
        const transformedChildren = React.Children.map(children, c => React.cloneElement(c, passthroughProps));

        return (
            <div className={ `${ tableClass ? `${tableClass} ` : '' }table` }>
                { transformedChildren }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

`except` is just a utility that grabs all of an Object's "own" properties **except** for the properties defined in the second argument (as an array of property names)

Before you go telling me to use Higher Order Components let me provide a little more detail. The reason for my designing the table this way was that I wanted folks to be able to use the control like below (where they can provide their own custom implementations).

```
<Table columnDefinitions={columnDefinitions}>
    <Row>
        <Cell/>
        <Cell/>
        <Cell/>
    </Row>
    <CustomRow />
</Table>
```

Even if I want to give up the transclusion-like approach - I'm not quite sure how I would go about doing this with a Higher Order Component since they seem to be better designed for more deterministic approaches. To clarify say we have an HOC for a `Card` and a `CardList`:

```
const CardListHOC = (Card) => CardList extends Component {
    // propTypes, etc...
    render() {
        const { items } = this.props;
        const passthroughProps = except(this.props, ['id', 'key', 'children', 'form', 'items']);

        return (
            {items.map(i => (<div className="card-list-wrapper"><Card {...passthroughProps} item={i}/></div>)}
        );
    }
}

const CardHOC = (Child) => Card extends Component {
    // propTypes, etc...
    render() {
        const passthroughProps = except(this.props, ['id', 'key', 'children', 'form']);

        return (
            <div className="card-wrapper">
                <Child {...passthroughProps} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The `CardListHOC` only takes a single type of `Card` so that means the `Child` component that I pass to the `CardHOC` is going to have to implement all the custom logic for all the custom types of cards I want to support based on the input data.

The problem with the `React.cloneElement` approach is that child elements are rendered first so on the first pass the child elements don't have props from their parents until they are "transformed" - so you end up with lots of inefficiencies and I can't have the `Row` component, for instance, require `columnDefinitions` as a prop unless I explicitly hand them down to every `Row` like this:

```
<Table columnDefinitions={columnDefinitions}>
    <Row columnDefinitions={columnDefinitions}>
        <Cell/>
        <Cell/>
        <Cell/>
    </Row columnDefinitions={columnDefinitions}>
    <CustomRow columnDefinitions={columnDefinitions}/>
</Table>
```

Is there a better way of going about this? Maybe there's a way with HOCs that I'm just not seeing? If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Martin, what did you end up doing in this case? I have the same problem where the children don't have the new props. Did you end up going the HoC route?

Comment: @geoboy https://github.com/jpollard-cs/flexable/blob/master/src/FlexableComponent.js

Answer (score 1):

As surprising as it might be-I was no more than yesterday-, React Elements aren't instancied with `React.createElement` (aka `<Element/>`). You can try, the class only gets instancied when the element gets mounted on the DOM. This is why `cloneElement` isn't inefficient, and this is why children elements won't be rendered before they're transformed.

That being said, you might like to take a look at React [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) for some magic powder.

Comment: Hmm I've had some weird behavior around required props ... I thought this was related to children being rendered before they are transformed but maybe it's something else... Time to pull the control out of the big project and develop in isolation.